# Запятые в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно расставить знаки препинания: "Государство материально поддерживает не только вдов и разведенных женщин, а даже одиноких, до 35 лет, не нашедших супруга"?

Answer (score 1):

§ 59. Обособляются несогласованные определения, относящиеся к определениям-прилагательным и имеющие значение уточнения: Сквозь нее [зелень] просвечивает голубое, в серебре, небо (М. Г.); Прошел в горницу, разделся, бережно повесил праздничные, с лампасами, шаровары (Шол.); Справа, у подножия сопок, расстилалось большое поле, покрытое высокой, в рост человека, травой (Чак.); Именно в тот канунный, перед бурей, год случились некоторые значительные для Ивана Матвеича происшествия (Леон.). (См. также § 79.)
При отсутствии значения уточнения такие определения не обособляются: Красное в горошек платье выделяло ее в толпе. (ПАС Лопатина)

В вашем случае запятые поставлены верно: одинокие, до 35 лет,.. (женщины). До 35 лет - несогласованное определение, имеющее значение уточнения.

Answer (score 0):

Запятые - верно, грамматика - не совсем.

Не стыкуется "не только..., а даже...". Возможно "**а**" лишнее.  Или изменить на "не только, **но** и".

Comment: Тоже так считаю .Правда, есть еще вариант "не только..,но даже". В любом случае, не "а", а "но".

Answer (score 0):

Не согласен. В тексте, насколько я понимаю, речь не об одиноких, до 35 лет, женщинах, а об одиноких женщинах, до 35 лет не нашедших супруга. Запятая после "лет" - лишняя.